# Extracting data from this object/array? How to do it

Tags: php, arrays, object

Here is a snippet of the print off of $wp_scripts

```
WP_Scripts Object
(

[base_url] => http://*****
[content_url] => http://*****
[default_version] => 3.5.1
[in_footer] => Array
    (
    )

[concat] => 
[concat_version] => 
[do_concat] => 
[print_html] => 
[print_code] => 
[ext_handles] => 
[ext_version] => 
[default_dirs] => Array
    (
        [0] => /wp-admin/js/
        [1] => /wp-includes/js/
    )

[registered] => Array
    (
        [utils] => _WP_Dependency Object
            (
                [handle] => utils
                [src] => /wp-includes/js/utils.min.js
                [deps] => Array
                    (
                    )
```

How would i Extract some data, for example "/wp-includes/js/utils.min.js"??

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to extract, give us example input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$wp_scripts->registered['utils']->src
```

Accessing object properties via `->`

Accessing array elements via `[/* String or integer here*/]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = new WP_Scripts;
$src = $object->registered['utils']->src;
```